# Sterling DB Windows mobile 10 support

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, sterling-db

I have a WP8.0 Silverlight app in store. It uses SterlingPhone as DB. I downloaded my app in a Windows Mobile 10 Insider Preview Version (v10.0.10536.1004) and it seems that data is removed after I exit the app.

I am using IsolatedStorageDriver:

```
Database = _engine.SterlingDatabase.RegisterDatabase<ItemsDatabaseInstance>(new IsolatedStorageDriver());
```

Has anyone faced this situation? I know Sterling is pretty old, but I think it should continue working on WM10.

In case I have to change to another Database Engine, I'd appreciate suggestions (my Data Model makes it very difficult to work with Sqlite due to nested objects).

EDIT:
Apparently Sterling is unable to find the existing database so recreates it each time the app is relauched.

[Isolated storage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCp5g.png)

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? I have the same issue with my WP8.0 app on Windows 10 Mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who found this post with the same issue, the problem lies in changed behaviour for string.GetHashCode on Windows 10 Mobile.

Sterling uses the hashcode of the database name in the path for the database. On Windows 10 Mobile the behaviour has changed and everytime the app is restarted a different hash is calculated and the path changes to the previous database is not found.

To get your app working again, get the SterlingDB code from CodePlex and change the code in the PathProvider class, in the GetDatabasePath method, then recompile your app. You can add a check to see if you are running on WM10 so users on WP8 continue to work with the old database.

The newer version of SterlingDB on GitHub doesn't appear to use the hashcode anymore so should also keep working.